# Solace nodejs api integration with Webpack

Tags: typescript, webpack-2, solace

I have an angular2 typescript webapp which is build with webpack. I am trying to integrate solclientjs into it, but I get the exception below

```
solclientjs-exports.js:34 Uncaught Error: Cannot find module "."
at webpackMissingModule (solclientjs-exports.js:34)
at load (solclientjs-exports.js:34)
at loadProduction (solclientjs-exports.js:44)
at new loader (solclientjs-exports.js:47)
at Object. (solclientjs-exports.js:72)
at webpack_require (bootstrap 79a17da…:52)
at Object. (home.component.ts:8)
at webpack_require (bootstrap 79a17da…:52)
at Object. (app.ts:17)
at webpack_require (bootstrap 79a17da…:52)
```

Can you please advise?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using [exports-loader](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/exports-loader) will enable you to package the library with Webpack.

Here's a sample `webpack.config.js` after exports-loader is used.

```
const path = require('path');

const solclientjs = path.resolve(__dirname, 'path/to/solclientjs-10.0.0/lib/solclient.js');

module.exports = {
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      solclientjs$: solclientjs
    }
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: require.resolve(solclientjs),
        use: 'exports-loader?window.solace'
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

A couple of things to note:

1. You need to use the browser version instead of the node version for Webpack. Packing the Node version of the library for use in the browser isn't supported and won't work.

   - The Node version uses a Node specific WebSocket library that won't work on browsers
   - The Node version doesn't include the full range of HTTP transports. For example, the browser version allows you to fallback to HTTP Comet transports. This is not available in the Node version.
   - The browser version includes browser-specific platform code to make things
     work better on specific browsers; none of this is
     present in the Node version.
2. For compatibility reasons, the browser version of the library is shipped so
   that it can be directly included with a <script> tag in a file. For browsers, it's highly recommended that the library be loaded with it. Examples can be found [here](https://github.com/SolaceSamples/solace-samples-javascript).

Answer (score 1):

The error is on line 44 of `solclientjs-exports.js`

```
var loadProduction = function() {
    return load("production", "./solclientjs.js");
};
```

Here is what `load()` does:

```
var load = function(type, file) {
    if (loaded[type]) return loaded[type];

    loaded[type] = require(file);
    return loaded[type];
};
```

It looks like `./solclientjs.js` cannot be found. Please verify whether `solclientjs.js` exists and is in the correct location.

Comment: The file is definitely there as my script does find solclientjs-exports.js, which is in the same directory as solclientjs.js.

Based on your code you are hard coding the path to "./"

But in Webpack "./" can mean a completely different directory while the script is executing.  Have you experimented with your api and Webpack, did it work for you?